# DBT manifest.json data type is null

Tags: google-bigquery, manifest.json, dbt

I'm creating a lot of stuff based on the manifest.json that dbt generates for me. But for whatever reason the "data_type" property for each column is always None in the manifest.json, even though I can see it in the catalog.json, I believe the data type is generated from the database.

How do I get the data_type attribute populated in my manifest.json file ?

Comment: Please provide more details, some examples, how it's processed. Based on the tags I guess you want to use DBT on BigQuery. What have you tried, what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi, the manifest.json is produced by the dbt-compile & dbt-run commands. Its not throwing any error. I've tried to follow the documentation: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/artifacts/manifest-json
but its not giving me much. There is however one clue:      "(A few node properties, such as compiled_sql, only appear for executed nodes.)"
and I think the data_type property is also this type of a property, but I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: On the other hand here is the documentation for the catalog.json which has the property which I want into the manifest.json (data_type) https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/artifacts/catalog-json

Comment: But the problem with the catalog.json is that I don't have column/table tags in there, which I do in manifes.tjson

Comment: what version of dbt are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some helpful answers from this [dbt Slack thread](https://getdbt.slack.com/archives/C2JRRQDTL/p1631748400331100):

### first reply (h/t Daniel Luftspring)

not sure if this is the only way but i'm running dbt version 0.20.1 you can specify the data_type as a column property in your schema.yml and it will show up in the manifest like so:

```yaml
columns:
  - name: city
    data_type: string
```

If you have a big project and wanted to automate this you could probably pull together a script to edit your schema files in place and sync the data types with your db using the information schema

### second reply (h/t Jonathon Talmi)

> FYI catalog.json has data type becaause it queries the metadata data
> tables in your dwh (e.g. info schema in snowflake) to contruct the
> catalog, but your traditional dbt compile/run/etc which. generates a
> manifest does not have such queries